# Reading data from serial port for barcode reader in C# language

Tags: c#

I want to read data from my USB barcode reader. For this, I've used a virtual COM port & connected to it on COM3. I can read the data into some note-pad or on Excel file. But, I'm unable to read data from serial port barcode reader using my following C# application.

My code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM3", 115200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BarCodeReader1.PortName = "COM3";
            BarCodeReader1.BaudRate = 115200;   // 19200;
            BarCodeReader1.Parity = Parity.None;
            BarCodeReader1.DataBits = 8;
            BarCodeReader1.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            BarCodeReader1.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            BarCodeReader1.RtsEnable = true;
        }

        private void cmd_Exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if ((BarCodeReader1.IsOpen))
                BarCodeReader1.Close();

            this.Close();
        }

        private void cmd_Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!(BarCodeReader1.IsOpen))
                    BarCodeReader1.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error opening/writing to serial port :: " + ex.Message, "Error!");
            }
        }
 
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();

            foreach (string port in ports)
            {
                richTextBox1.Text += port + (char)13 + (char)10;
            }
        }

        private void BarCodeReader1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            string l_Data = BarCodeReader1.ReadExisting();
            textBox1.Text = l_Data;
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I read the Barcode, event : BarCodeReader1_DataReceived is not getting executed. Kindly help to resolve the problem.

Comment: Please add the manufacturer and model number of the barcode reader to your post. You'll need to refer to the documentation for your barcode reader to find how to change the barcode reader from acting as a keyboard device to a USB Serial Port device - it may be as simple as scanning a barcode in the user manual.

Comment: `But, I'm unable to read data from serial port barcode reader using my following C# application.` <- This does not describe the problem. Please describe the observed behavior.

Comment: Adding a carriage return and a linefeed (`+ (char)13 + (char)10`)  can be done _better_ using ` + Environment.NewLine`.

Comment: Since your code is referencing Windows.Forms you could skip the SerialPort implementation altogether and inspect the Key messages that are being sent by the USB scanner. This way you can use any off-the-shelf USB scanner without worrying about the make or model, and you won't have to tell your customers to reconfigure their standard USB scanners in order to use your app. Here's a simple working demo you can [clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/barcode-scanner-01.git) from GitHub to see if this is a good fit for your project.

Comment: What  user09938 says. This has nothing to with code but your scanner is configured as keyboard wedge and not sending the event over serialport. With datalogic scanners there is a barcode you can scan to put the device into serial mode and it should work

Comment: My BarCode Reader is Wenglor make (Model : CSMH009, USB connectivity). I set it to RS232 Serial Port thru it's software.

Comment: [Wenglor CSMH009](https://www.wenglor.com/en/1D2D-and-Barcode-Scanners/1D2D-Handheld-Scanners/1D2D-Handheld-Scanner/p/CSMH009). For the user manual, click _Downloads_ and then expand _Operating Instructions_. Download the PDF by clicking the desired language (ex: _EN_) - the software may allow one to change the settings instead of having to scan the barcode.  For the _Virtual COM Port driver_, expand _Soft- and Firmare_ - if you've installed the software, the Virtual COM Port driver may already be installed.

Comment: It appears that the QR codes start on page 24 of the user manual - it may be possible to change the settings using the software instead of scanning the QR codes.

Comment: Rather than _RS232_, you may try _USB virtual COM - multiple ports_ (QR code: M20346_01 on page 25 of the user manual). If that doesn't work, one can reset to factory defaults, by scanning QR code:  _M20177_01_

Comment: It appears that you haven't subscribed to the `DataReceived` event (`BarCodeReader1.DataReceived += BarCodeReader1_DataReceived;`). Also, you may consider moving all of the code related to `BarCodeReader1` from the constructor to `Form1_Load`.

Comment: See page 44 of the user manual for QR code to scan so that the data has the appropriate ending (ie: _CR_, _LF_, or _CRLF_). Then ensure that you set the [SerialPort.NewLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.newline?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) property. Then one can use [SerialPort.ReadLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.readline?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0).

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the datawedge setting of the scanner, you have not shown if the DataReceived property is set. It wont work if that is not set

```
    SerialPort port = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        try {
            port = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
            port.Open();
            port.DataReceived += BarCodeReader1_DataReceived;
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

Comment: Where shall I write this logic ? Kindly explain.

Comment: in the form1 constructor is the easiest option and I edited that ion, once you have more exp check out the formloaded event.  but that is out of the scope of the question